# Changing files on remote machine using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to change a file on remote Linux vm, and redirect it's output to another one (on the same machine) using Paramiko. It should be simple, but I'm obviously missing something here. I use tr command to replace every blank space for tab then redirect it to another file:

```
command= "tr ' ' '\t' <file1 .txt> file2.txt"
```

This command actually works fine when executed inside shell, but when I send it over SSH:

```
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

It creates an empty file, and redirects its output to stdout. Can anyone give me an explanation on why is this happening? I tried to look in documentation, but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should put quotes around your command:

```
command='tr " " "\t" < /tmp/file1.txt > /tmp/file2.txt'
```

Comment: You're right, I forgot to put it in my original post. But that wasn't the problem, since I already did it in my code.

Comment: This command is working well when put in ssh.exec_command(). file1.txt is read and file2.txt is written on the remote host as wanted. Do you still have an issue?

Comment: Yes. I think I found the reason why is this happening, though I'm not sure how to solve the problem. When I execute a command solely, it works fine. But when I first execute a command to find an absolute path of the file, it redirects the content to stdout. When I looked inside documentation for exec_command() it says: " A new Channel is opened and the requested command is executed."